# payment information depends on shipping information magento

Tags: magento-1.9

**Payment information** depends on **shipping method**

In **Shipping Method** when selected **Standard Shipping 2-7 days** then hide **Cash On Delivery** and **vise versa**

when shipping method is fixed then hide check money order if check stranded shipping then hide cash on delivery

i already add this code in \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\method.phtm

getMethods(); $oneMethod = count($methods)
__('No Payment Methods') ?>
getCode(); if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') { if($_code == 'checkmo') { continue; } } ?>

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

credits : [Elavarasan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2798621/elavarasan) for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604267/magento-onepage-checkout-hide-payment-method-depending-on-shipping-method)

In the link, they used different shipping and payment methods. you need to change the codes according to your requirements.

```
shipping_method => flatrate_flatrate
 paymet_method   => checkmo
```

As for I got, you trying to hide some payment methods based on shipping method. For this you don't need to observe things at all. Simply you can do this, just follow me,

Every methods(in one page check out) post the methods which are chosen to the next level. so you can get the shipping method which are chosen, in payment method level. Just print the post things in

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml
```

in this add below one,

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

So now you can get the shipping methods which are chosen previous step. And note it, so now, you can add just simple logic (if else) condition in same file for hiding payment,

For example here I want hide `check / money order` payment method, if shipping method is `flat`. Here the payment method code is `checkmo`. you can get payment method code by simply printing that variable like `echo  $_code = $_method->getCode();` in same file. so here just add simple if else ,

```
  <?php
    $methods = $this->getMethods();


    $oneMethod = count($methods) <= 1;
?>
<?php if (empty($methods)): ?>
    <dt>
        <?php echo $this->__('No Payment Methods') ?>
    </dt>
<?php else:
    foreach ($methods as $_method):
       echo  $_code = $_method->getCode();


if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
if($_code == 'checkmo') {
    continue;
}
}
?>
```

Here,

```
 if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
if($_code == 'checkmo') {
    continue;
}
}
```

checks the shipping method and skip the payment method which we don't want to display. That's it. Please comment here if you have any doubt.

**Note:**

```
 shipping_method => flatrate_flatrate
 paymet_method   => checkmo
```

Comment: Bro i apply as it but its not working when  i check flat in payment  method Check / Money order  is still display

Comment: Bro is it possible when i select stranded shipping 2-3 days in  shipping method then only Bank transfer display in payment method other payment method off

Comment: @DanishAli yes, you need to use the respective shipping & payment method codes and try......

Comment: Hello Sir (@Baby in Magento) i have applied as suggested by you but its not working sir kindly check 3 images still 1 month+ i am unable to solve it  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlI3F.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE4In.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r7mZ.png

Comment: @DanishAli please update the question with updated  code & images......

Comment: please give me any recommendation updated question is here  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197223/magento1-specific-shipping-display-specific-payment-option