# Magento1 specific shipping display specific payment option

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to show specific payment method when specific shipping is selected

Already Implement this solution but not works for me

code update in

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml

```
<?php
    $methods = $this->getMethods();
    $oneMethod = count($methods) <= 1;
?>
<?php if (empty($methods)): ?>
    <dt>
        <?php echo $this->__('No Payment Methods') ?>
    </dt>
<?php else:
    foreach ($methods as $_method):
     echo  $_code = $_method->getCode();

if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
    if($_code == 'checkmo') {
        continue;
    }
}    

?>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604267/magento-onepage-checkout-hide-payment-method-depending-on-shipping-method

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the given link is not a good solution in my point of view. Because it checks post data in a phtml page, which is not at all good approach.

Instead you need to look for any events to do your job. Luckily there is an event for you to do that. The event is: `payment_method_is_active`.

This event is fired from the method `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::isAvailable()`. This method will be checked by Magento when it prepares the available payment methods for checkout, which makes this event best to avoid certain payment methods as per our need.

Set up an observer which listens to the event `payment_method_is_active` in your module and your observer should look like this.

```
public function disablePaymentMethodByShippingMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $result = $observer->getResult();
    $methodInstnce = $observer->getMethodInstance();
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    $shipMethod = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();

    //if ship method is flatrate_flatrate, then disable payment method: checkmo.
    if ($shipMethod == 'flatrate_flatrate' && $methodInstnce->getCode() == 'checkmo') {
        $result->isAvailable = false;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Here we are just checking the shipping method opted is `flatrate_flatrate`. If yes, then set `$result->isAvailable` to `false`. If this is set to false, then Magento won't add that payment method into available payment methods list.

Hope you get the idea. I didn't test this code. But this is the right way to do this.

Comment: hello bro can i place this code at    \app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Model\Method\Abstract.php  ?

Comment: bro i found this link is it suitable for me    http://www.webspeaks.in/2013/12/dynamically-enabledisable-payment-method-in-magento.html

Comment: No you cannot place this code in that file. It is basically become a core edit. You should know how to create a module in magento and how to configure an observer through it, in order to use my answer.

Comment: The link is also provides another solution, but still it uses a class rewrite. This solution is more clean and it is the best way to do this work